# Correct usage of To vs On

Tags: prepositions

I had recently been chided for inadvertently using "on" to describe strapping an accessory (on/to) a car mirror - for obvious reasons.
While "on" may be perceived as inappropriate or even impoilte, my question is:
Is using "on" in this context grammatically incorrect?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Ins and Outs of Prepositions 2nd Ed., page 103,  would support your usage of  'on', but of course it also supports the usage of 'to':

On
Usage 5: On indicates surface contact.
Pattern: verb+noun+on+noun
The child pasted the picture on the page
Typical verbs: glue, hold, paste, stick

To
Usage 8: To can indicate attachment.
Pattern 1: verb+noun+to+noun
We will paste the wallpaper to the bedroom walls.
She pinned the flowers to my lapel.

Pattern 2: be+part participle of verb+to+noun
Your paper is stapled to mine
The gum is stuck to my shoe.
Typical verbs used with these patterns: add, adhere, affix, apply, attach, glue, hold, nail, paste, pin, press, screw, sew, staple, stick, tape